# Error reading a .chm file

Tags: windows-7, chm

I have a .chm file. On one desktop computer (Windows 7) it works fine; on another computer with the same OS, it shows the following error on the same file:

> Navigation to the webpage was canceled
>
> What you can try:
>      Retype the address.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking on the file, go to properties, and see if there is there is a button to "Unblock".

If so, click it.

Additionally, if you're trying to open the file from a network share, copy it to the local computer's hard drive, and try opening it from there instead.

Comment: Geniuse! saved my day

Comment: @EladBenda: Saw your post on meta, which was what got me here. For posterity, which of those two suggestions was the fix?

Comment: so there was point posting on Meta! cost me 1 points :( the first one did the work.

Comment: Hah, I shouldn't have said that :) But yes, in this case, it attracted attention.